# Retrieve the distance from a point to the nearest raster pixel with a given value in Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, raster, postgis-raster

### Context

I have the table (hs_buildings) in my Postgresql DB containing the Point location of my buildings (hs_buildings.coordinates). Then I have a raster containing the land use in stored in a Postgresql raster table (named hs_raster_values).

The resolution of the raster is 100x100 and all geometries are in epsg 2056.

### Question

How can I retrieve the shortest distance from my buildings location to a pixel with a given value (let say 170005)

### Transforming the raster pixel into points

The following query work but is not efficient at all and would take too long if run over the entire building table.

```
WITH hs_points AS
(
    WITH gv AS 
    (
        SELECT
            (ST_PixelAsCentroids(hs_raster_values.geometry, 1, true)).*
        FROM hs_raster_values
        WHERE hs_raster_values.raster_id = 1
    )

    SELECT
        (gv).x,
        (gv).y,
        (gv).val,
        gv.geom 
    FROM gv 
    WHERE val = 170005
)
SELECT 
    ST_Distance(hs_points.geom, hs_buildings.coordinates)
FROM hs_points, hs_buildings
WHERE hs_buildings.id = 1
ORDER BY hs_buildings.coordinates <-> hs_points.geom

LIMIT 1
```

### With built in Postgis raster function

By looking at the documentation, I have seen that there is a Postgis function made to achieve this results : [ST_MinDist4ma](https://postgis.net/docs/RT_ST_MinDist4ma.html). However, the documentation is very poor and I find myself stuck to understand the appropriate argument I have to pass in the funciton.

I tried this query:

```
WITH building_pixel AS 
(
    SELECT 
        (ST_WorldToRasterCoordX(hs_raster_values.geometry, hs_buildings.coordinates),
        ST_WorldToRasterCoordY(hs_raster_values.geometry, hs_buildings.coordinates)) AS xy
    FROM hs_raster_values
    INNER JOIN hs_buildings ON ST_Intersects(hs_buildings.coordinates, hs_raster_values.geometry)
    WHERE hs_raster_values.raster_id = 1
    AND hs_buildings.egid = 1
    AND ST_Intersects(hs_buildings.coordinates, hs_raster_values.geometry)
)

SELECT 
    ST_MinDist4ma(170005, building_pixel.xy, hs_raster_values.geometry) AS min_distance
FROM hs_raster_values, building_pixel
WHERE raster_id = 1;
```

And get the following error:
`ERROR:  function st_mindist4ma(integer, record, raster) does not exist LINE 14:  ST_MinDist4ma(170005, building_pixel.xy, hs_raster_values.g...`

Does any one know I can use this function?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like there might be an issue with the arguments you're passing to ST_MinDist4ma. The function might not accept the types you're providing. Have you checked the function signature and ensured the data types match?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help. I was indeed using ST_MinDist4ma incorrectly. I use it like this now:

```
SELECT
        ST_Value(ST_SetSRID(ST_MapAlgebra(
            hs_raster_values.geometry, 
            ARRAY[170005]::integer[],
            'ST_MinDist4ma(double precision[], int[], text[])'::regprocedure
        ), 2056), hs_buildings.coordinates) AS min_distance
    FROM hs_buildings
    INNER JOIN hs_raster_values ON ST_Intersects(hs_raster_values.geometry, hs_buildings.coordinates)
    WHERE hs_raster_values.raster_id = 1 AND hs_buildings.id =1
```

Which give me a raster as output and then I try to find the associated value at the location of the building. However, I get the following error:

```
NOTICE:  All input rasters do not have bands at indicated indexes. Returning empty raster

ERROR:  Could not find raster band of index 1 when getting pixel value. Returning NULL 

SQL state: XX000
```